# How to check value overlap using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How to avoid range overlapping in C# entity framework

```
select * from globalsettings 
where minvalue between 3 and 6 OR maxvalue between 3 and 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int checkRange = (from globalSetting in db.GlobalSetting
                  where ((globalSetting.MinValue >= minValue 
                          && globalSetting.MinValue <= maxValue) 
                          || (globalSetting.MaxValue >= minValue 
                                && globalSetting.MaxValue <= maxValue))
                  select globalSetting)
                  .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer certainly works well, but I thought I'd point out another way to do this just for curiosity's sake since you mentioned you are using Entity Framework.
You could use an [ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var vals = db.GlobalSetting.Where("(minvalue between 3 and 6) or (maxvalue between 3 and 6)");
//if you just want the count of these:
int checkRange = vals.Count();
```